# Installing an APK using pm command

Tags: android, command

I tried updating an APK using this code:

```
Process process;
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", "pm install -r -d"+MyApk.apk});
```

but it does not work.

This works well when I use it with adb like:

```
adb shell su -c pm install -r -d /system/app/Community-debug.apk
```

It also works fine if it has to ask for user permission in order to install like using the intent method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your application would need to run as System user to access this level of commands. It cannot be done in any way if your app is distributed using standard channels, e.g. Google Play, installing from SD card, or installing by ADB. None of these would let your app breach the security.

Having said that, there **is** a way to get it working, but that way is for **privileged distribution only**. Your app must:

- include `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in the AndroidManifest
- be signed with the certificate which is used to sign the rest of the system
- be pre-installed in one of the privileged locations: `/system/app`, `/system/priv-app`

Once your app satisfies these requirements, it can execute commands like `pm install`, even without the `su`

Needless to say that such options are only available to large bodies like telecom providers who sell their own-branded devices.

Answer (score 6):

Your solution will only work on rooted devices.

In order for it to run on all devices, firstly, you need a cooperation from the device manufacturer to put your app under /system/priv-app. Putting your apk there will give you system privileges enabling you to perform the install.
On top of that, you need to add android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES to your manifest file. 
Finally, add these lines to your code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 " + MyApk.apk);
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm install -r " + MyApk.apk);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it doesn't require your app being signed with systems certifiacte

Comment: I have same requirement...my device is rooted, but still Its not upgrading the application

Comment: I am running this on Android 9 and all these steps are satisfied and it still does not perform the uninstall or install.