# uiDevice.executeShellCommand("pm uninstall " + Constants.APP_PACKAGE); does not return output string from shell

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I want to uninstall an apk when I execute UiAutomator test.

I am using below command for that and it is working fine. It uninstall the app from the device.

```
String output = uiDevice.executeShellCommand("pm uninstall " + Constants.APP_PACKAGE);
```

However, when I check the value of output string it is blank. I want to check if the app is uninstalled or not to perform next steps in the script. How to get the output of the executeShellCommand in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Assumng you are using Uiautomator2.0 . If then I wonder how above code worked without exception. Is uiDevice an instrumentation instance ? `UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation())` has a public method `executeShellCommand` which returns a String. 
Try below code-

```
private UiDevice mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
String output = mDevice.executeShellCommand("pm uninstall " + Constants.APP_PACKAGE);
```

Exact code will give `Success` in case of successful uninstall.

Comment: Can we use this code for installing apk file into device/emulator? if, Yes, Can you please provide the code for the same..

Comment: Use `pm install`.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423519/installing-an-apk-using-pm-command